# How to change Oxy Plot tracker vertical line thickness?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, oxyplot

We are using Oxy Plot plugin in wpf project, it is great tool but I have one small issue. If I change application window size and reset plot axis zoom, vertical line or tracker can disappear.

Seems that it is so thin that it becomes invisible. Oxy plot doesn't have any vertical/horizontal line settings, only color. Maybe where are possibility to change tracker vertical line settings with help of WPF?

I looked through GitHub source and seems it's realy don't have such property.
https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/94db37a0f609e4df794feee9c431cc1848e52e6a/Source/OxyPlot.Wpf/Tracker/TrackerControl.cs

Also I tried to redraw tracker, invalidate plot, redraw whole plot but nothing get results.

This is oxy plot view code - horizontal line is disabled and vertical line has only color settings.

```
                <oxy:PlotView Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Model="{Binding Path=XYPlotModel}" Controller="{Binding PlotController}" Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="10,10,10,105">
                    <oxy:PlotView.DefaultTrackerTemplate>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <oxy:TrackerControl Position="{Binding Position}" HorizontalLineVisibility="Collapsed" LineExtents="{Binding PlotModel.PlotArea}" LineStroke="Blue">
                                <oxy:TrackerControl.Content>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="0" />
                                </oxy:TrackerControl.Content>
                            </oxy:TrackerControl>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </oxy:PlotView.DefaultTrackerTemplate>
                </oxy:PlotView>
```

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place... look [HERE](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/94db37a0f609e4df794feee9c431cc1848e52e6a/Source/OxyPlot.Wpf/Themes/Generic.xaml) instead... :O)

Answer (score 1):

Checking the generic templates code [here](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/master/Source/OxyPlot.Wpf/Themes/Generic.xaml), you can style the lines and properties like

```
<Style TargetType="oxy:TrackerControl">
    <Setter Property="LineStroke" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```